# Use the mobile phone's microphone instead of the computer's microphone

Tags: python, pyaudio, microphone

I am trying to record audio in a file and it is already working in the computer but when I connect my mobile phone to the localhost to be able to manipulate the web and check how is it seen, I realised that when I try to record an audio even if I am connected from my mobile phone it is listening to the computer's microphone instead of the phone's microphone. Is there any way to solve this?

```
def generate():
    chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
    channels = 1
    fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
    seconds = 4
    filename = "/Users/enekoiza/Desktop/easy-peasy/test2.wav"

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

    print('Recording')

    stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                    channels=channels,
                    rate=fs,
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                    input=True)

    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

    # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
    for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

    # Stop and close the stream 
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    # Terminate the PortAudio interface
    p.terminate()

    print('Finished recording')

    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'w')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
```

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean by "connect my mobile phone to the localhost to be able to manipulate the web and check how is it seen"?

Comment: I am running a server in the localhost on my computer and I am connecting my phone to the localhost to check how the CSS is seen in a screen like the mobile phone, check if the backend and jquery works in the mobile phone, but I realised that even if I am in the mobile phone it is using the microphone that is connected to the computer that is running the localhost server.